# View reStructuredText (Sphinx) docstrings in iPython?

Tags: python, ipython, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docstring

Is there a way to have IPython fully render reStructuredText (for Sphinx) docstrings when you type the following:

```
help foo
```

or:

```
foo?
```

I find it *super* distracting to try to read help docs in IPython when it shows the raw markup.  reST is great for Sphinx documentation, but really clutters up simple help lookups.  I can't be alone on this one...?

Google has been no help on this one.

Comment: As far as I know, not yet. Contributions are welcome - ask on mailing lists or IRC about where to start.

Comment: One way you could add the feature is to render the docstring to HTML and then parse and colorize (or just print the text) the output.

Comment: There's also a text builder for Sphinx, that might be easier than using HTML.

Comment: I agree, viewing sphinx docstrings in ipython is not really human readable. I have tried using "Consolidated Fields" as a compromise: viewing docstrings in interpreter is better, but some of Sphinx's nice features are lost.

Comment: It has been discussed: http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/IPython-User-Pretty-rendering-of-docstrings-td5003265.html but nothing has been implemented AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you for the link- very encouraging.  I think Brian Granger said it best: 

"Personally, if the notebook became able to handle markdown+latex 
docstrings, I would never user reST for any new project."  

I'm already using Markdown in docstrings instead of Sphinx, as I see a few projects aiming to build API documentation from docstrings. This, I think, is the only thing for which I currently need Sphinx.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible in IPython, but have a look at [Spyder](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/): You can open an IPython console from within the IDE. Docstrings are rendered as HTML.